# remove all from beginning of LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, java-7

I was looking through the [LinkedList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#method_summary) for Java 7 and noticed something curious.  there does not appear to be a "remove before (or after)" type of method.  For example, If I have a 100 element LinkedList, and I want to remove the first 20 elements, Java seems to force you to remove them one at a time, rather than moving the start pointer to the 21st element and deleting the link between 20 and 21.  It seems like this is an operation that can be done in O(1) time, instead of O(n) time as Java seems to force you to do it.

Am I missing something here, or is it just a glaring hole in Java?

**EDIT**

I am aware of the `sublist(int, int)` method in the List interface.  I still think that this will be slightly less efficient than the generic "chop off the first (or last) n" use case.

**EDIT 2**

Touche to everyone who pointed out that finding the nth element is not O(1).  Regardless of the ease of chopping off the first n-1 elements, it still takes O(n) time to find the nth.

However, as Dilum Ranatunga points out, there is the possibility that an iterator already exists at the given position.  In this case, it would still be useful to say "I am here, remove all before me".

Comment: You can't remove the last 20 elements either...

Comment: How can it be done in O(1) time when you have to start from first element to get to n-th?

Comment: "Chopping off first/last n" requires traversing that many next or previous pointers with linked list. That's what `subList()` will do for you. But your question is interesting for the case where you're already at the 20th (or 21st) element, and you decide you want everything before or after this point should get removed.

Comment: Actually, `sublist(int, int)` is O(1).

Comment: @GarrettHall, OK, I'll bite. How does `java.util.LinkedList` -- note, nothing fancy like skip lists -- know how to jump to the `i`-th element in O(1)?

Comment: It stores an offset value in a wrapper class for the original LinkedList (please see my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still an O(n) operation no matter what you do.

You don't have direct access to the individual nodes of the linked list, so you would have to traverse the list first to get access to the 21st node. Once you were there it would be O(1) to 're-head' the list, but it's still O(n) for the entire, atomic operation.

Comment: Yes, unless you have an iterator that's already at the correct position. Some application logic tells you that all elements preceding current element needs to be removed. What now?

Comment: Use a more appropriate implementation of list that can generate sublists and copy them in constant time?

Comment: @DilumRanatunga Then it was O(n) to iterate to that point. Again, the entire operation is still O(n), so you're only saving on the constant, not on the order. The entire, atomic opeation is O(n). I agree with Affe that the situation you describe, while not a corner case, is not a common case either, and doesn't need to be in the default implementation. For what it's worth, `LinkedList`s are rarely used outside the classroom.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga Furthermore, the iterator is going to iterate over elements of type `E`, not elements of type `Entry<E>`. So even in the situation you describe, that's not going to help any. Any attempt at doing that will break encapsulation.

Comment: `ListIterator` is stateful and allows read/modify/delete of the current element. As such it behaves as a "current entry". The problem with using it as a long-lived reference to an Entry is that list iterators are fail-fast. But long-lived is not necessary in the current context.

Comment: Point taken on `ListIterator`. It is certainly conceivable to do in that manner. When you think about it, it all boils down to the design decisions made by the author (Josh Bloch), we can only speculate as to why he didn't include this on the `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList inherits a sublist method from List interface.  Information can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int, int)

Comment: But subList is still an O(n) operation. OP is asking why isn't there an O(1) operation.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, I figured that it would go to that index in memory and return that as the new linked list.  I haven't looked at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `list = list.subList(21, list.size())` to get a [sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) from 21 to the end of the list.

The operation is O(1), but you do not get a `LinkedList` back, you get an `AbstractList.SubList` which acts like a wrapper class for the original `LinkedList`, delegating methods with the sublist's offsets.

Although this is constant time, it is important to note this is not a new list.  If your list size went from n to m, subsequent linear-time methods called on the list will still run in O(n) not in O(m).

Comment: Just be aware that `subList` returns a view rather than a copy.

Comment: Is it possible to get a LinkedList out of the sublist, without then having to go through the O(n) operation of creating links between each node in the AbstractList?

Comment: Yes, it is constant time.  However, linear methods will still run in O(n) where n is the original size of the list.

Comment: @GarrettHall If the list size not change, then how does this become useful in the case described above?  i.e. I need to retrieve and manipulate a list containing the last m elements.  If I didnt care about working with greater efficiency, I would just continue working on the original list

Comment: @ewok Use an ArrayList and you won't have that problem because it can access elements in O(1) time.

Comment: @GarrettHall true, but using an ArrayList will make the removal of elements (and, as is possible in my use case, insertion at the front) more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to immediately jump to the Nth element because each prior node contains the address of the Node.next (the next node in the chain).  So it has to naturally traverse 20 elements causing O(n) runtime.

For example:

[Node 1, address of Node 2] -> [Node 2, address of node 3] -> etc...  -> [Node 20, address of Node 21]

You cannot get the "address of Node 21" without getting to the Node 20 first, and to do so you need to "address of Node 20" from Node 19 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What is your algorithm for finding item n in O(1) time?  This would still be an O(n) operation to locate the nth item and set it as the head.  You would save some intermediate pointer assignments compared to 20 removes, but not a huge gain.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `java.util.List` defines the API [`listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28%29). `ListIterator` has [`previous()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous%28%29).

So the idiom you want is:

```
// some loop construct {
  listIter.previous();
  listIter.remove();
}
```